# Not able to understand this Elasticsearch query

Tags: elasticsearch

```
{
  "query": {
    "nested": {
      "path": "product_vendors",
        "query": {
            "bool" :{
                "must" : {
                    "bool" : {
                        "should" : [
                            { "terms": {"product_vendors.manufacturer_style":["FSS235D-26","SG463-1128-5","SG463-2879-4"]}},
                            { "terms": {"product_vendors.id":["71320"]}}
                        ]
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
  }
}
```

I have above elastic query, not able to understand this. Would anyone please explain what it means and what documents it will return?

Update :  @christinabo  , i tried your query , and results returned , but here some small issues , apart from the matched documents , two more additional documents are returning in those documents only vendor_id is matching , may i know why two extra unmatched documents are returning , do we need to some attribute or something to make sure strict search and return is allowed , can please suggest on this .

Answer (score 0):

By observing the query, I can understand that there is a `nested` object in the data. I can imagine that it has this structure:

```
product_vendors: {
   'id': 'the_id',
   'manufacturer_style': 'some style'
}
```

In order to query a nested object, you need a `nested query`. This is why you have the nested keyword there. In a nested query, you need to specify the `path` (`product_vendors`) that leads to the embedded fields (`id`, `manufacturer_style`).

Then, the query defines a bool query with the `must` keyword, which means that the query which follows must appear in matching documents. In this case, what it must appear is another bool query, defined with the `should` keyword. This contains two `terms` sub-queries (one for `manufacturer_style` and one for `id`) and means that the matching documents should match one or two of them. Each sub-query queries the embedded field by specifying the whole route of the nested object, using the dot (i.e. `product_vendors.manufacturer_style`).

I would expect the query to return you the documents that match **at least one** of the `terms` queries, with the documents that match both to have higher score.

I hope that this explanation gives you an overall idea of this query.

More about bool queries from the documentation [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-bool-query.html).

Comment: you are awesome , so great , very good , deep explanation , thank you so much .I have one query after reading your answer , how to modify the query , so that it will return documents in such a way that , each document must have product_vendor.id as specified  and must contain atleast one product_vedors.manufacturer_style from the array , that means like below sql qeury 

select * from product_vedors where product_vedor.id = 71320 and product_vedors.manufacturer_style in ("FSS235D-26","SG463-1128-5","SG463-2879-4"). that means each document returned must be vendor is as given.

Comment: Glad that helped! I created this [gist](https://gist.github.com/christinabo/e11e4cec593890008a6ab87b17095a59) with the query you mentioned. 'Terms' is supposed to return documents that match any of the provided terms so this should work, if I correctly understand your question.

Comment: i tried the query framed by you , but no result returned . but am sure their are documents which have vendor id and manfacturer_style specified above . may i know why this is not working

Comment: It is difficult to know why exactly is not working, as I cannot see nor the data format neither the mapping that you have used. Given the info you have given, this is an idea of how the query should be formed. It might need some modification though.

Comment: the https://gist.github.com/christinabo/e11e4cec593890008a6ab87b17095a59 , this query , is not as per our requirements , here we need manfacturer_style  also , so we need that in must not side should , because if we put it in should it is like those values not mandatory in the reult documents

Comment: @Bravo I updated the gist https://gist.github.com/christinabo/e11e4cec593890008a6ab87b17095a59. I added both queries inside a 'must' array. I hope I got what you want to achieve.